# Translation of "foliage trip"

Tags: traduction

What is the translation of “foliage trip” in French?

[Foliage trip](http://www.scubamom.com/travels/fallfoliage/) = trip in the forest to watch the colorful leaves, typically during the fall season.

[image]

Comment: foliage trips are made in cars. You look for places to stop along the way. You might take a walk, but generally,  you look for "look-out spots", stop the car and, for example, take a picture. This is not a promenade or balade.

Comment: @ɑ̃sakʁamɑ̃ Correct, it may happen in another season, e.g. winter if late, or spring if in Southern Hemisphere. More generally, it's a trip to check out the leaves.

Comment: @Lambie I don't think it has to be made in cars. Oher means of transportation such as walking or biking are ok too as far as I know.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Note that spring is still spring in Southern Hemisphere, it just starts in late September until late December.

Comment: @Lambie Somewhere below you state: ...“Fundamentalists find some odd things to say.” Interesting! ... Just to know what you mean by “fundamentalist” so that I can know if I my Le Robert is one or not, would it be a fundamentalist or non-fundamentalist (linguistically) thing to say that using “balade” or “promenade” (or even “randonnée”) in French is inappropriate when discussing traveling/taking trips in cars?

Comment: I think it is very funny when I read "I don't think it has to be made in cars". Right, you are. If you live near Vermont, they have a TRAIN that takes you on a foliage trip....can't remember the specifics.

Comment: @Papa Poule Fundamentalists refers to Christian fundamentalists who interpret the Bible literally. Someone was trying to show that this trips are not always in the fall. Yes, you can also take a trip up/down the Amazon to "see the foliage". :)

Answer (score 6):

There is no concise French equivalent but I found a couple of ***rando-feuilles***. If you need an established expression, I would translate "foliage trip", despite the lack of explicit reference to the leaves, by ***balade en forêt***.

Note: as the English expression does not necessarily imply a specific season, I refrain to use *automne* in its translation.

Edit: After a closer look to what is actually a foliage trip, it seems it usually span multiple days so ***randonnée*** would better fit than *balade*.

One might then translate "fall foliage trip" by ***randonnée d'automne*** or ***randonnée d'automne en forêt***. Where there is a forest, there are trees, and where there are trees, one can reasonably expect some foliage to be visible...

Also, thanks to Aaron's suggestion: ***Randonnée couleur sylvestre***.

---

Il n'existe pas d'équivalent aussi concis en français mais j'ai trouvé quelques **rando-feuilles**. S'il faut une expression bien établie, je traduirais cependant *foliage trip*, malgré l'absence de référence précise au feuillage, par **balade en forêt**.

Note : l'expression anglaise n'imposant pas nécessairement une saison particulière, j'évite d'utiliser *automne* dans sa traduction.

Edit : Après avoir regardé de plus près ce que peut signifier *foliage trip*, il semble qu'il s'étend souvent sur plusieurs jours, **randonnée** est dans ce cas plus indiqué que balade.

S'il faut traduire *fall foliage trip*, ce serait donc **randonnée d'automne** ou **randonnée d'automne en forêt**. Là où il y a une forêt, il y a des arbres, et là où il y a des arbres, on peut raisonnablement s'attendre à voir des feuillages...

Aussi, grâce à la suggestion d'Aaron, **randonnée couleur sylvestre**.

Comment: I think the English phrase _does_ imply necessarily the fall season.

Comment: @ɑ̃sakʁamɑ̃ Pour deux raisons, la première est que l'on rencontre souvent *fall foliage trip* et que l'expression que souhaite traduire Franck est *foliage trip*, la deuxième est que j'ai trouvé, mais j'avoue que c'est avec difficulté, un article d'un journal de 1965 qui dit *a railroad club with headquarters in Boston, is sponsoring a spring foliage trip on Saturday, May 15.* et une page facebook intitulée elle aussi *Spring foliage trip*.

Comment: @ɑ̃sakʁamɑ̃ L'échange avec Gilles n'avait rien à voir, il s'agissait d'un anglicisme qui lui avait échappé (*idiom* != idiome).

Comment: @Mitch You are more than likely correct. To be honest, I wasn't aware of that idiom before this question was asked.

Comment: +1 OP does not specify "**fall** foliage trip" and I've seen spring foliage trip before. @Mitch

Comment: Je ne sais pas à quel point c'est idiomatique, mais l'adjectif "sylvestre" me vient à l'esprit : une randonnée sylvestre, une balade sylvestre.

Comment: @Aaron Oui, on trouve aussi « Randonnée couleur sylvestre » que j'ajoute à ma réponse. Merci pour la suggestion.

Comment: @Laure 1) I can't imagine a trip to see leaves growing in the spring. 2) to be frank, I've never heard the phrase before. It may well be a set phrase or not, so a literal translation should be fine.

Comment: @Mitch That would be blossoming flowers instead of growing leaves, but using foliage might be debatable in that case. Here are the very rare cases search engines are able to find:  [newspaper](https://www.newspapers.com/newspage/45356610/),  [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/events/1562549617407034/)  and [church paper](http://www.fbcharrison.org/hp_wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/April-2016-Challenger.pdf) (off line)

Comment: @jiliagre OK, then you're right, I suppose 'fall' is not implicit in 'foliage trip'.

Comment: @Mitch Let's say it is *only* implicit in 99.9 percent of the cases...

Comment: @jlliagre I guess my point is that it's not especially a special phrase whose nuance needs to be captured so specifically by some tortured translation process. A trip to view leaves changing/flora/nature. 'Foliage' is a technical word in English (not rare, but not particularly common). It was chosen for the English phrase because there was no more common term for it (in a sense translating a much longer phrase into a slightly obscure two word phrase)

Comment: Not religious at all. It _is_ latinate, so it feels like a more educated register. It sounds like a biologist said it rather than a poet, like you're walking through the jungle.

Answer (score 5):

Je ne connais pas de terme idiomatique équivalent en français. (Cela dit il n'est [pas si répandu que ça en anglais](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/347542/where-do-people-take-foliage-trips).) Je pense qu'on dirait plutôt [balade d'automne](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22balade+d%27automne%22) ou [randonnée d'automne](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22randonn%C3%A9e+d%27automne%22). Ce n'est pas forcément une balade en forêt, mais l'automne évoque quand même fortement les arbres en feuilles (les « couleurs d'automne »). C'est un peu un terme consacré, parce que quand on parle d'automne, j'ai l'impression que c'est toujours avant la chute des feuilles : après, on parle de « [randonnée des feuilles mortes](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22randonn%C3%A9e+des+feuilles+mortes%22) ».

Comment: @jlliagre Effectivement. C'est tout de même un peu idiot qu'un idiome ne soit pas idiomatique (et pas exactement un idiotisme).

Comment: ni un idiomatisme...

Comment: What would you say when the foliage trip is taken in spring? *Balade de printemps en forêt*, *rando feuilles vertes* ?

Comment: Il n'y a pas de terme idiomatique en français pour *fall foliage trip* parce que c'est associé aux couleurs particulières et très typiques des forêts du Vermont et du Canada en automne. La coloration du feuillage dépend non seulement de l'espèce d'arbres (ou du mélange d'espèces) mais aussi des conditions climatiques, c'est donc une convergence de plusieurs données qui donne cet aspect aux forêts de l'est américain.

Comment: Il n'y a pas l'équivalent en France, même la magnifique forêt de Lyons (plus belle hêtraie en Europe) ne se parent pas de ces couleurs spectaculaires en automne. Peut-être y a-t-il  d'autres pays au monde qui ont l'équivalent, mais les américains étant très fort sur le plan commercial et communicationnel ils se donnent du mal pour mettre leur patrimoine en valeur.

Comment: A foliage trip is by car.

Comment: foliage trip is synonymous with the fall season.  You don't take a foliage trip in spring....

Answer (score 4):

For such a trip in Fall, regardless of the weather, I think “couleurs d’automne” could be combined with “balade” to give **“[Une] [Balade [aux] couleurs d’automne”](http://www.ardennes.com/balade-couleurs-d-automne-avec-l-office-de-tourisme/charleville-mezieres/tabid/22511/offreid/ca45fc14-510c-40d0-a28c-4a3d2a6252eb/detail.aspx)**, which is described on the linked site of Les Ardennes’ Office of Tourism (without the “aux”) as:
« … une balade afin d'apprécier les magnifiques couleurs des arbres qui peuplent [leurs] parcs et jardins ».

If the trip is specifically designed to occur during a period of three or more days of nice weather following the first Fall freeze (or if you don’t care about the strict definition of “Indian Summer"), you could perhaps better emphasize the importance of the magnificent colors by adding that word to Erwann’s good answer, just as Joe Dassin did several times in his song [*L'été indien*](http://www.paroles.net/joe-dassin/paroles-l-ete-indien)
:
  « [Une/un] Balade/voyage **aux couleurs** de l'été indien » ,

which phrasing (with *balade*) is used [here](http://www.lenouvelliste.ch/articles/lifestyle/loisirs-et-culture/balade-aux-couleurs-de-l-ete-indien-241384) in a title of an article in *Le Nouvelliste*.
(lyrics of Mr Dassin’s song retrieved from *Paroles.net*)

Answer (score 3):

[(Fall) foliage sightseeing trip]. Personne n'a évoqué le ***[paysage](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/paysage) d'automne*** et donc voilà. Le paysage c'est la « vue d'ensemble, qu'offre la nature, d'une étendue de pays, d'une région » (TLFi). Et ce paysage, on peut le *voir*, l'*observer*, l'*admirer* etc. Au delà de l'activité de déplacement dans la forêt du coin, on peut donc aussi *partir en voyage pour aller/afin de* le voir, l'observer ou l'admirer, et peut-être parler d'un *voyage d'observation des paysages d'automne*. On a pensé à *[villégiature](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vill%C3%A9giature) d'automne*, mais ça semble plutôt imprécis si on tente d'exprimer l'attrait pour le [feuillage](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/feuillage) qui motive le déplacement. Mais il s'agit par définition généralement de tourisme saisonnier (à l'automne ; on a aussi l'adjectif automnal) ; parfois d'[écotourisme](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9cotourisme/10909956). L'idée du *chasseur d'images (de paysages) d'automne* pourrait être utile si le déplacement était motivé par la photographie. Enfin je suis tombé par hasard sur cette description, d'une magnifique facture à mon avis, au sujet d'un *paysage d'automne* justement :

> *31 octobre 1852. Lancy.* — Promenade d'une demi heure au jardin par une
>   fine pluie. Paysage d'automne. Ciel tendu de gris et plissé de
>   diverses nuances, brouillards traînant sur les montagnes de l'horizon;
>   nature mélancolique. Les feuilles tombaient de tout côté comme les
>   dernières illusions de la jeunesse sous les larmes de chagrins
>   incurables. Nichée d'oiseaux babillards s'effarouchant dans les
>   bosquets et s'ébattant sous les branchages comme des écoliers entassés
>   et cachés dans quelque pavillon. Le sol jonché de feuilles brunes,
>   jaunes, et rougeâtres, les arbres à demi dépouillés, les uns plus les
>   autres moins, fripés de roux de citron, d'amarante, les massifs et les
>   buissons rougissants ; quelques rieurs encore : roses, capucines,
>   dahlias égouttant leurs pétales ; les champs nus, les haies
>   appauvries; le sapin, seul vigoureux, vert, stoïque, éternelle
>   jeunesse bravant le déclin ; — tous ces innombrables et merveilleux
>   symboles que les formes, les couleurs, les végétaux, les êtres
>   vivants, la terre et le ciel fournissent à toute heure à l'œil qui
>   sait les voir, m'apparaissaient charmants et saisissants. [...]
>
> [ [*Fragments d’un journal intime*](https://books.google.com/books?id=JggbAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22ciel%20tendu%20de%20gris%20et%20pliss%C3%A9%22&pg=PA55#v=onepage&q=%22ciel%20tendu%20de%20gris%20et%20pliss%C3%A9%22&f=false), d'[Henri-Frédéric Amiel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri-Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric_Amiel),
>   ed. de 1884 ]

Évidemment on peut parler d'un paysage avec n'importe qu'elle saison en la précisant.

---

[Like green(s), going out of the city, generic]. Plusieurs réponses et commentaires m'ont cependant aussi convaincu d'un sens moins étroit pour l'activité en question, faisant abstraction des saisons et reposant sur le simple attrait de la verdure pour ainsi dire :

> Aller en forêt [pour y regarder les arbres ou y cueillir des *têtes de violons* (crosses de fougères)].
>  Partir en pleine [nature](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/nature/53894) [et en profiter pour regarder les arbres (plutôt que le béton)].

Avec infinitif et un complément indiquant le but (ici avec *pour*). Très proche du mot à mot de la définition présentée en question. L'essence du *trip* c'est *aller à quelque part, partir* ; avec le lieu verdoyant, soit la forêt, ou un endroit ayant peu été façonné par l'être humain (en pleine nature).

Answer (score 2):

Personnaly I prefer "promenade" instead of "balade", but both are correct for small (< 1 day) walk. For a **trip**, I think that a better translation would be "excursion" because you expect to travel to a distant destination with a goal, and spend more time there.

Now for foliage, as mentioned before there is no equivalent (creating an adjective from a noun is not possible in French, so it is difficult to be concise.) "en forêt" would be a good choice, but it is a little too generic. So maybe you could add **contemplative** to insist on the "AWE" of nature.

to conclude, I would say

> excursion contemplative en forêt

Comment: The adjectives *feuillu* and *feuillagé* exists but wouldn't work anyway because the trip itself has no leaves and doesn't look like a foliage either.

Comment: What I mean is that OP used the noun foliage as a complement of the noun "trip" a bit like an adjective (even if the adjective foliaged exists, because it wouldn't work in this case) as a shortcut of foliage's trip (or trip to see the foliage).

Comment: foliage trips are typically made in cars.  You drive to the place.

Comment: @Lambie Oh, that kind of rules out *randonnée* then, would be *excursion* like radouxju already suggests.

Comment: @jiliagre Ce n'est ni une balade ou randonée quoique cela peut inclure les deux une fois arrivé "sur les lieux". foliage is les couleurs des arbres en automne.

Comment: @Lambie That would be a figurative meaning. Foliage is with no doubt closely related with the French *feuillage* and is documented to have exactly the same meaning [mw](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foliage) [tlfi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/feuillage)

Comment: @jiliagre here foliage is not feuillage, unless Canadians have decided to say it that way.  You would not say that in French from France. On ne va pas à la montagne pour voir les feuillages. Mon dieu. :) en BIOLOGIE, le mot est feuillage. Mais pas pour fall foliage trip

Comment: @Lambie Not "*les feuillages*" but ["*le feuillage*"](http://blog.niceartphoto.fr/tag/feuillage/). It is a [common](https://testclod.blogspot.fr/2013/11/feuillage-dautomne-peinture-huile-au.html) French word. Unless I'm missing what you wrote, I didn't tell they are pronounced the same way, just that they proceed from the very same middle French word (*fueillage*) and they didn't diverge that much unless the new acceptation you support *couleur des arbres en automne* is proved to be widely accepted. PS: by the way, you mistype my username, starts with JLL, so I'm not notified of your comments.

Comment: Ouais, j'ai des gros problèmes d'orthographe en français malgré le fait que je sois interprète. Ou bien on connait le phenomène culturel du [fall] foliage trip ou bien on ne le connait pas. Ici, bien des commentaires feraient sourire un anglophone puisque le sens de foliage trip (plus la photo) montre exactement de quoi il s'agit. Bien sûre, feuillage est un mot ordinaire. En anglais aussi. Mais /foliage + trip/ c'est comme la choucroute. Ça se mange garnie. Indiscutablement...:)

Answer (score 2):

foliage trip is typically in a CAR to SEE the autumn colors.
**This sounds HORRIBLE** but a TRIP here is:

un déplacement en voiture (ou moto) pour voir les couleurs des arbres en automne.
This is not a walk. The colors are seen "from a distance" and/or above. You drive up or down highways with VIEWS or LOOK-OUT points. Or  you might go to a lake with lots of trees, woods surrounding it.

Here are the semantic meanings that have to come across in French:
trip= un déplacement, a trip is either by car or motorbike.
**foliage**=les **arbres en automne**, c'est-à-dire: les couleurs des feuilles sur les arbres en automne
**foliage is always in autumn in this expression.**

Translation: **une excursion en forêt ou en montagne pour voir les couleurs d'automne**

excursion est plus jolie que déplacement....

Comment: What about the "Annual Spring Foliage Trip to see God's creation unfold."

Comment: That is  not a usual thing. Fundamentalists find some odd things to say. Look at the OP's picture. That is usually what it is: a fall foliage trip

Comment: They can miss a number of things. But here foliage trip means fall foliage, look at the picture.

Answer (score 0):

«Voyage 'Été indien'.» Variants: «itinéraire, circuit».